# Divide data to increase read performance

Tags: cassandra

we have 8  cassandra nodes in 2 DC  configuration and we have around 250k  record insertion per second and our ttl is 1 year  ,  Recently we upgraded  to 3.0.14  . Our main problem is slow read performance .

to improve this  we increased compaction period from 1 hour to 1 week .( Full compaction still needs to run ) But now  we are thinking to install new cassandra nodes and divide data to 2  pieces  ( 6 months period each ) and new casandra nodes can be responsible only querying  first 6 months .Is this possible  to move data like this ? is the procedure to follow ?  thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but this makes little sense to me: new casandra nodes can be responsible only querying first 6 months. what do you mean? will data be moved from one cluster to another data once it gets old?

Comment: Our server connected to  SAN  ,  so 4  servers in DC  share SAN pool  . I mean  . I  mean install  one  cassandra server ( same  dc and  share same SAN )  and  move half  of  sstable  from cassandra node1  to   new  cassandra node 2 ( I can  repeat this operation  4 times )  . (  From unix  level  these are just files   but  there are indexing  and so  )  ,My question  is this feasible  and  what is procedure ?